# how to pass a list from controller to visual force page

Tags: apex, visualforce

```
public with sharing class DisplayProfilePictureController{

    public Attachment file{set;get;}
    public Boolean hasPicture{set;get;}
    private String parentId{set;get;}

    public DisplayProfilePictureController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController){
        this.parentId = stdController.getId();
        this.hasPicture = false;

        List<Attachment> attList = [SELECT ParentId, Name, Id, ContentType, BodyLength FROM Attachment 
                                        WHERE ParentId =: this.ParentId];
        if(attList.size() > 0 ){
            this.file = attList.get(0);
            this.file.Body = Blob.valueOf('AuxString');
            this.hasPicture = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: <apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="DisplayProfilePictureController" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false">
    
</apex:page>

Comment: If you have more details to add, please [edit] your question instead of adding comments. It'll really help us help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just going by your class your main issue is most likely the **scope** of the attList.

As you have it, the scope is local to the instantiation and not the entire class.

Changing to:

```
public with sharing class DisplayProfilePictureController{

    public List<Attachment> attList {get; set;}

    public DisplayProfilePictureController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController){

        attList = [SELECT ParentId, Name, Id, ContentType, BodyLength FROM Attachment 
                                        WHERE ParentId =: this.ParentId];
    }
}
```

Will allow you to access the `attList` on the page most likely using a repeat:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!attList}" var="a">

{!a.Name} - {!a.ParentId} 

</apex:repeat>
```

Without knowing what you are trying to do it is hard to provide more detail